# Definite Integration with Trigonometric Substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm working on a question that involves using trigonometric substitution on a definite integral that will later use u substitution but I am not sure how to go ahead with this.

$$\int_1^2\frac1{x^2\sqrt{4x^2+9}}dx$$

My first step was to use $\sqrt{a^2+x^2}$ as $x=a\tan\theta$ to get...

$$2x=3\tan\theta :x=\frac32\tan\theta$$
$$dx=\frac32\sec^2\theta$$

Substituting:

$$\int\frac{\frac32\sec^2\theta}{\frac94\tan^2\theta\sqrt{9\tan^2\theta+9}}$$

The problem here is how do I change the limit it goes to?

$$\frac43=\tan\theta$$
and
$$\frac23=\tan\theta$$

Following DR.MV's answer so far..

$$\frac29\int_{\tan^-1(\frac23)}^{\tan^-1(\frac43)}\frac{\sec^2\theta}{\tan^2\theta\sqrt{9\sec^2\theta}}d\theta$$

$$=\frac29\int_{\tan^-1(\frac23)}^{\tan^-1(\frac43)}\frac{\sec\theta}{\tan^2\theta}d\theta$$

$$=\frac29\int_{\tan^-1(\frac23)}^{\tan^-1(\frac43)}\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin^2\theta}d\theta$$

Now $u=\sin\theta$ so $du=\cos\theta d\theta$

$$=\frac29\int_{?}^{?}\frac{1}{u^2}du$$

This is where I am stuck now...

Comment: Do you need to know those values?  Maybe you can just live with them as values of inverse trig functions.  After all, your answer is likely to involve other trig functions evaluated at $\theta$.

Comment: No problem! Denote by $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ the angle such that $\tan\theta_1=\frac{4}{3}$ and $\tan\theta_2=\frac{2}{3}$. In the end you will find expressions involving $\tan$ and $\sec$.

Comment: Sorry could you explain this a bit more? Do you mean for me to continue my integration from $\arctan\frac23$ to $\arctan\frac43$

Comment: Compute the indefinite integral and express the result in function of $\tan\theta$.

Comment: @Panthy Yes.  Exactly.  If you know the value of one trig function at an angle it is generally pretty easy to find the value of the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a typo in the current post.  After enforcing the substitution $2x=3\tan \theta$, the integral ought to read

$$\begin{align}I&=\int_{\arctan(2/3)}^{\arctan(4/3)}\frac{\frac32 \sec^2\theta}{\frac94 \tan^2\theta\sqrt{9\tan^2\theta+9}}d\theta\\\\
&=\frac29 \int_{\arctan(2/3)}^{\arctan(4/3)}\frac{ \sec^2\theta}{ \tan^2\theta\,\sec \theta}d\theta\\\\
&=\frac29 \int_{\arctan(2/3)}^{\arctan(4/3)}\frac{ \sec^2\theta}{ \tan^2\theta\,\sec \theta}d\theta\\\\
&=\frac29 \int_{\arctan(2/3)}^{\arctan(4/3)}\cot \theta \csc \theta d\theta\\\\
&=\frac29 \left.(-\csc \theta)\right|_{\arctan(2/3)}^{\arctan(4/3)}\\\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{13}}{9}-\frac{5}{18}\end{align}$$

---

**NOTES:**

**Remark 1:**  When making a substitution of variables in a definite integral, the limits of integration change accordingly.  In this example, the substitution was $x=\frac32 \tan \theta$.  When $x=1$ at the lower limit, $\tan \theta =\frac23\implies \theta =\arctan(2/3)$.  Similarly,  when $x=2$ at the upper limit, $\tan \theta =\frac43\implies \theta =\arctan(4/3)$.

**Remark 2:**
To evaluate $\sin (\arctan(2/3))$, we recall that the arctangent is an angle whose tangent is $2/3$.  A picture sometimes facilitates the analysis wherein we draw a right triangle with vertical side of length $2$ and horizontal side of length $3$ forming a right angle.

Note that the angle the hypotenuse makes with the horizontal side is $\arctan(2/3)$.  Inasmcuh as the hypotenuse is of length $\sqrt{2^2+3^2}=\sqrt{13}$, we see $\sin(\arctan(2/3))=\frac{2}{\sqrt{13}}$ and thus $\csc (\arctan(2/3))=\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}$.

Comment: will continue from this point and update you! thanks

Comment: i updated my answer but still confused

Comment: OK ... posted the full solution to assist.  Please let me know how I can improve the answer.  I just want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: is the way I did it wrong? im not so confident dealing with csc sec and stuff but either way im reallly not sure how you evaluate $(-csc\theta)_{arctan(\frac23)}^{arctan(\frac43)}$

Comment: The arctangent gives an angle whose tangent is the argument. So, if an angle has a tangent of $2/3$ then its sine is $\sqrt{2^2+3^2}=\sqrt{13}$.  Likewise, the sine of an angle whose tangent is $4/3$ is $\sqrt{4^2+3^2}=5$.  How else can I improve the answer?

Comment: Is there a link you can direct me to with pictures or something that explains this concept which I'm clearly lacking...? I don't understand :(

Comment: @Panthy I edited to add an explanation.  Please let me know how else I can help.

Comment: OK One last question. I understand what you did, but if I could not have thought of converting it to csccot would there be any further simplification on my answer where i have $\frac{1}{u^2}$

Comment: Yes.  $\int \frac{du}{u^2}=-\frac{1}{u}+C$ since for $n\ne 1$, we have $$\int x^ndx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C$$

Comment: I know that part, but changing the limits of integration there would it be any simpler? or it would be the same as you have done here

Comment: Well, the limits on $u=\sin \theta$ would be different.  We note from before that at the lower limit, $u=\sin \theta=\sin \arctan(2/3)  =\frac{2}{\sqrt{13}}$ and at the upper limit, $u=\sin \arctan(4/3)  =\frac{4}{5}$

Comment: I think it would be easier your way so I dont have to change the limits more than one time...

Comment: Another way would be to arrive at $-csc \theta$ and change back to the original variable $x$ (i.e., $-\frac29\,\csc \theta =-\frac19\,\frac{\sqrt{4x^2+9}}{2x}$) and use the original limits on $x$.

Comment: ah ha! thats the way I had learned but didnt know how to get there! ^ that is what I need! thanks!@

Comment: You're welcome!!  My pleasure.  Very pleased to hear that you have it now.  Well done!

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}\int\frac{\frac32\sec^2\theta\,\mathrm d\mkern1.5mu\theta}{\frac94\tan^2\theta\sqrt{9\tan^2\theta+9}}&=\frac29\int\frac{\mathrm d\mkern1.5mu\theta}{\sin^2\theta\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta}}=\frac29\int\frac{\lvert\cos\theta\rvert\,\mathrm d\mkern1.5mu\theta}{\sin^2\theta}\\[1ex]
&=\frac29\int\frac{\cos\theta\,\mathrm d\mkern1.5mu\theta}{\sin^2\theta}\qquad\text{since}\enspace 0\le\theta<\dfrac\pi2\\[1ex]
&=-\frac2{9\sin\theta}
\end{align*}
Some trigonometry will let you determine the bounds for $\sin\theta\;$ from the bounds for $\tan\theta$: since $0\le\theta<\dfrac\pi2$, we have:
$\cos\theta=\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta}}$, hence $$\sin\theta=\tan\theta\cos\theta=\frac{\tan\theta}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta}}=\frac{\cfrac{2x}3}{\sqrt{1+\cfrac{4x^2}9}}=\frac{2x}{\sqrt{4x^2+9}}$$
so that the indefinite integral is:
$$-\frac{\sqrt{4x^2+9}}{9x}.$$

Comment: There appears to be an error of omission.  The secant squares term disappeared in the second integral.

Comment: It's been replaced with $\cos^2\theta$ in the denominator;

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: OK.  Yes.  But the integrand is missing the term in the denominator, namely $x^2=\frac94 \tan^2 \theta$.

Comment: By the way, I was not the down voter.  In fact, I very very rarely down vote.  Rather, I like to neutralize down votes by giving an up vote.

Comment: theres a missing tan^2 in the denominator from the beginning

Comment: It was a general question,  not aiming at you particularly. I also very rarely downvote. I prefer comments that help improve the answer, when it's possible.

Comment: @Panthy; Was it in the original post, or was it added?

Comment: @Bernard Glad to hear that.  I abhor the trigger-happy down voting!

Comment: It was a type as Dr.MV pointed out in his post so I changed it later on...

Comment: @Panthy: I updated my answer, which is simpler (but the end of the first answer is a *must-know*.

Comment: Yes this one follows my answer but the confusion now from here is to convert $\theta$ to x :P

Comment: You don't have to convert to $x$ unless you want the indefinite integral.

Comment: well that doesnt really solve the problem though because the original problem was to integrate it from 1 to 2 right?

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_1^2\frac1{x^2\sqrt{4x^2+9}}dx = \int_a^b\frac{\frac{2}{3}\sec^2\theta}{\frac{9}{4}\tan^2\theta\sqrt{9\tan^2\theta+9}}d\theta$$

where $a = \tan^{-1}\frac{2}{3}$ and $b = \tan^{-1}\frac{4}{3}$

$$ \int_a^b\frac{2\sec\theta}{9\tan^2\theta}d\theta = \left(-\frac{2\text{cosec}\theta}{9} \right)_a^b$$

Hint: $\text{cosec}\left(\tan^{-1}\frac{4}{3}\right) = \frac{5}{4}$, $\text{cosec}\left(\tan^{-1}\frac{2}{3}\right) = \frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}$

EDIT: let $\tan^{-1}\frac{4}{3}=d $

$$ \frac{4}{3} = \tan d$$
$$\frac{4}{3} = \frac{\sin d}{\cos d} $$
$$ \frac{1}{\sin d} = \text{cosec}\ d = \frac{3}{4}\sec d$$

$$ \sec^2d = \tan^2 d + 1 = 1+ \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^2 = \frac{25}{9}$$
$$\sec d =\frac{5}{3}$$

$$ \text{cosec}\ d = \frac{3}{4}\times \frac{5}{3} =\frac{5}{4}$$

You can do the same for the second one.

Comment: how do you know that?

Comment: could you please elaborate im new to that kind of thing... sorry if i sound stupid

Comment: I'll explain further in my solution.

Comment: @Panthy, I hope the explanation helps.